# hibernate join table mapping

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I want to map two entity classes:

```
@entity
Class A{    
 private long A_ID // primarykey    
 private long userID // not a  primarykey    
}

@entity
Class B{    
 private long B_ID // primary key    
}
```

I want to join A and B where A_ID = B_ID. Is there any way to map both of them by using join table/association class that can have A_ID, B_ID and userID? I am not sure if this is possible?

```
Class A_B{    
 private long A_ID     
 private long userID     
 private long B_ID     
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate use of PostgreSQL sequence does not affect sequence table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288740/hibernate-use-of-postgresql-sequence-does-not-affect-sequence-table)