# Hibernate+Postgresql: PK not starting from 1 (PG sequence created starting from 1)

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, sequence

I have a table with a primary key of SERIAL type.
This primary key is affected by a sequence like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE swq
INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
START 1 CACHE 1;
```

My question is: why the primary key, after a first execution of the `saveorUpdate()` method it creates the first record, but inserting the id field as ZERO (0) instead of ONE(1)?

---

From a comment by the OP:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "table", schema = "schem") 
public class tableBE implements java.io.Serializable 
{ 
  private int idmotiv; 

  @Id @Column(name = "_id", unique = true, nullable = false) 
  public int getIdmot() { return this.idmot; }
}
```

Comment: please add mapped class definition and sample code

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name = "table", schema = "schem")
public class tableBE implements java.io.Serializable {

 private int idmotiv;`
`@Id
    
     @Column(name = "_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
     public int getIdmot() {
      return this.idmot;
     }`

Comment: Those classes were generated in Eclipse via Hibernate plugin.
But I think the problem is from the PGdatabase side. I just create this entity and call the method `getcurrentsession.saveorupdate(entidad)`

Comment: follow @Viswanath D solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @GeneratedValue & @SequenceGenerator annotation configuration. Below is the example.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="Hib_Seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="Hib_Seq", sequenceName="swq")
private int idmotiv;
```

Comment: Also, you can check this [http://www.javabeat.net/jpa-annotations-generatedvalue-sequencegenerator-tablegenerator/](link)

Comment: Becareful in case you want to code this lines:
` @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="LICENSE_SEQ")
`
With Hibernate that causes that the sequence increments from 50 to 50. As it's mentioned in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288740/hibernate-use-of-postgresql-sequence-does-not-affect-sequence-table