# How to use custom table sequence with hibernate-5?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an existing db with the following schema and sequence:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT travelit_hotels_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.my_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 500791
  CACHE 1;
```

My `@Entity` mapping makes use of the sequence:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "my_seq")
private Long id;
```

As of `hibernate-5`, I'm using the following property:
`hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true`

Result: when I create a new entity, it gets the following id assigned: `500744`.

Which is < START of the SEQUENCE, and already exists in my `postgres` DB!

Why?

Comment: the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288740/hibernate-use-of-postgresql-sequence-does-not-affect-sequence-table) here , wasnt helpfull ?

Answer (score 0):

When using `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = true`, hibernate would by default create a sequence with `INCREMENT 50`.

As described [here](https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/jpa-hibernate-generatedvalue-with-sequence-on-oracle/), the generated id will then be `SEQ-49`. This creates conflicts with existing databases that have been generated with hibernate < 5.

Solution: limit the `allocationSize` to 1 for your existing sequence generators:
`@SequenceGenerator(.., allocationSize = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

proper annotations should be:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_generator", sequenceName="my_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

if you just have sequence on database, hibernate not override it. To change suquence you can delete from database and change in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

update to update daatabase or create to drop all and create again (tables and sequences)

Comment: `strategy = SEQUENCE` and `initialValue = 1` are the defaults. No need to add them explicit.